# Handling onclick events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a list which contains links. I am using this code to access them:

```
function initAll() {
 
 var allLinks = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("a");
 for (var i=0; i< allLinks.length; i++) {
    allLinks[i].onmouseover = showPreview;
    allLinks[i].onmouseout = function() {
         document.getElementById("previewWin").style.visibility = "hidden";
         allLinks[i].onclick=mainProcess;
        }
    }
}

function mainProcess(evt){
    alert(this.value);
    false;
}
```

This is not the exact code, what I am trying to do is that I need to identify link is clicked  and perform some function on the basis of link clicked. I don't know where code needs to be modified... Page is giving error on the `allLinks[i].onclick=mainProcess(this);` line.

Now the problem is that I don't know how I should handle all the three events?

Answer (score 1):

1) You're setting the `onclick` property of each of the links to be the value *returned by* `mainProcess()` - which always returns false. So, in effect, you're writing `allLinks[i].onclick = false;`

2) When you define an event handler directly, the argument that gets passed to it when the event fires, is the event object - not the element it was fired on.

To figure out the element, you can either look in the event object, or (since the handler has been added to the element itself) simply use `this`, as that will refer to the link element

```
for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
   allLinks[i].onclick = mainProcess;
}

function mainProcess(event) {
{
    alert(this.value);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Oh !!! i got it asctually i am first using onmouseover then onmouseout and then onclick .So this is never going out on onclick event ....actual code is like:

Comment: var allLinks = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("a"); for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {     allLinks[i].onclick = mainProcess(this); }  function mainProcess(Link) {     {         alert(Link.value);         false;     }

Comment: function initAll() {
  
  var allLinks = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i=0; i< allLinks.length; i++) {
  allLinks[i].onmouseover = showPreview;
    allLinks[i].onmouseout = function() {
  document.getElementById("previewWin").style.visibility = "hidden";
  allLinks[i].onclick=mainProcess;
  }
 }
}

    function mainProcess(evt){
 
 {
  alert(this.value);
  false;
 }
}

Now the problem is that how will i handle all the three events ...?

Comment: @abhinavsingh: Please edit your original post to include all the code - it's pretty hard to make sense of it in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
   allLinks[i].onclick = mainProcess;
}

function mainProcess(event) {
{
    alert(this.value);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You'll still have a problem - the argument passed to `mainProcess` will be the event object, not the link element. It should be `alert(this.value);` if OP wants the link's value property

Answer (score 0):

You do need to pass this to `mainProcess(link)`. As stated in http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html "No parentheses!" and "this" chapters. Check it out, there's an example there too. Should be everything you need.